# Unable to serve static file from flask server

Tags: python, flask

I have a index.html file, which has the absolute path 'c:\project\web\frontend\index.html'

I am trying to return it using the following function

```
@webserver.route('/')
def home()
     return webserver.send_static_file(path)
```

I have verified that the path is correct by accessing it directly in the browser.

I have tried to replace '\' with '/' without any luck.

It is running on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at flask's documentation for [send_static_file](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=send_static#flask.Flask.send_static_file). You'll see that it says that it's used internally by flask framework to send a file to the browser. If you want to render an html, it's common to use [render_template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=send_static#flask.render_template). You need to make sure that your index.html is in a folder called templates first. 
So I would do the following:

```
@webserver.route('/')
def home()
     return flask.render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: yes, but since this is a static HTML, I though I could use send_static_file. The issue was that I did not see that the file must be under a predefined "static folder". Once I defined the the path to be static in the app definition, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had to define the path to be the static_folder, when creating the flask object. Once I defined the folder to be static, the html page was served.